# Different form/filter/view-templates for different roles

Tags: forms, authentication, view, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have an admin dashboard with many functionalities such as create, edit, delete, activate and deactivate blog articles. I use [this `ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac` GitHub repository](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac) for access control.

Let's say I have three different roles with different permissions. Each of this roles should create blog articles but they have different required fields to fill out.

My question is, whats the right way to implement such behavior.

Is it better to create different view templates with different forms and filters for each of this roles? In my controller actions i render the view template with the given form/filter for the current user.

Or is it better to inject my `AuthorizationService` in form and filter to make them dependent to the current user? So i will only have one form/filter and one view template.